# Copy an entire row from sheet 2 which contains any value from column A on sheet 1, into sheet 3

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to be able to copy any row from sheet 2 which contains any value from column a in sheet 1. Copied and pasted into sheet 3.

I found this code online but cell value is specific. I have about 80 values so individually listing them would take to long.

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")
    If **Cell.Value = "131125"** Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you assign a variable for your range that you would like to be assessed: `Dim myRange as Range, myCell as Range` then you can do `set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A15")` as the cells that you are checking for and do another `For Each myCell in myRange`  `If Cell.Value = myCell.Value Then`  and finally wrap off with `Next myCell`

Comment: Or Store the values in an Array and then use Autofilter to copy them across?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor thank you for the response. I don't have any knowledge with excel coding, so would you be able to comment the exact code I should input. Thank you!

Comment: Can you maybe give an example for the first array that would be pasted?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyThings()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ans As Integer
    On Error GoTo ISAIDRANGE
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("what do you want to copy?", "Select Range", Type:=8)
    ans = MsgBox("the whole row?", vbYesNo)
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("where do you want to paste", "Select Range", Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng1.Parent.Activate
    Select Case ans
        Case Is = vbYes
            rng.Rows.EntireRow.Copy rng1.Rows.EntireRow
        Case Is = vbNo
            rng.Copy rng1
    End Select
ISAIDRANGE:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Err.Number = 424 Then ans = MsgBox("that's not a valid range", vbExclamation, "I meant a VALID range")
End Sub
```

Comment: Now, I wouldn't want to do this 80 times, but with a little effort you can take pieces of that code with pieces of the code you found earlier and make something more useful for your specific requirements.